# Finding a polynomial with some constraints on the roots, derivative and sign

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

How would one in general go about finding some polynomial $\Pi$ defined on say $[a, b]$ such that

- $\Pi(a) = \Pi(b) = 0$,
- $\Pi'(a) = d_a, \Pi'(b) = d_b$ ($d_a, d_b$ fixed in advance) and
- $\text{sgn}(\Pi)$ is continuous on $(a, b)$ (that is $\Pi$ does not switch sign or become zero in between the fixed roots $a, b$).

Comment: Try a cubic polynomial. It gives you just enough degrees of freedom.

Comment: The idea is this: if $d_a,d_b$ are opposite signs, there is no polynomial that can satisfy the last condition. If one of them is zero, the cubic polynomial must have a multiple root at that zero derivative. If they are both the same sign the cubic must automatically satisfy the sign condition.

Comment: The first two, specifying function and derivative values, leads to Hermite interpolation. I'm not sure how much the third changes things. You might also look up splines under tension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find cubic polynomials $f$ and $g$ that are zero at $a$ and $b$, are positive on $(a,b)$ and such that $f'(a) = 1$, $f'(b) = 0$, $g'(a) = 0$, and $g'(b) = 1$. (Hint: $f$ is a multiple of $(x-a)(x-b)^2$.) Then $\Pi = d_a f - d_b g$ will do the job (since $d_a$ and $d_b$ must have opposite signs if they are both nonzero).

If $d_a = d_b = 0$ and you don't consider $\Pi = 0$ to be valid, then you can use a quartic polynomial like $(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore the no-zeroes-in-between requirement first.

First, choose an arbitrary polynomial with sufficiently many free parameters, for example $\Pi(x) = rx^3+sx^2+tx+u$, or for this case more cleverly $\Pi(x) = (rx+s)(x-a)(x-b)$.

Now let's look at the equations $\Pi(a) = 0, \Pi(b) = 0, \Pi'(a) = d_a, \Pi'(b) = d_b$. If we evaluate $\Pi$ there, we'll get a system of **linear** equations in $r, s, t$ and $u$. This should be easy to solve. You will get some $\Pi$ such that the boundary equations are satisfied.

Next, you'll want to check whether the no-zeroes requirement is satisfied. For the case $\text{sgn}(d_a) \neq \text{sgn}(d_b)$, this should already suffice. For the case $d_ad_b > 0$, this isn't satisfied, and it never will be, because any continuous function satisfying those boundary conditions will have a zero in $(a, b)$.

This leaves the case $d_a = d_b = 0$. Using the method above, you will get $\Pi = 0$, which doesn't suit your constraints. In this case you can try using more free variables to get a whole set of solutions to your linear equation system, for example by adding a $qx^4$ into the term or something. This will yield more solutions which are better suited to fit your constraints.

Or you could be really clever and simply manually choose the polynomial $(x-a)^2(x-b)^2$ to satisfy your requirements.